# reshape Pandas dataframe by appending column to column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

i do have a Pandas df  like (df1):

```
     0 1 2  3   4  5
   0 a b c  d   e  f
   1 1 4 7  10  13 16
   2 2 5 8  11  14 17
   3 3 6 9  12  15 18
```

and i want to generate an Dataframe like (df2):

```
   0  1  2 
0  a  b  c
1  1  4  7
2  2  5  7 
3  3  6  9
4  d  e  f 
5  10 13 16
6  11 14 17
7  12 15 18
```

additional information about the given df:

1. shape of given df ist unknown. b = df1.shape() -> b = [n,m]
2. it is a given fact the width of df1 is divisble by 3

i did try stack, melt and wide_to_long. By using stack the order of the rows is lost, the rows should behave as shown in exmeplary df2 . I would really appreciate any help.

Kind regards Hans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `np.vstack` and `np.hsplit`:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(np.vstack(np.hsplit(df, df.shape[1] / 3)))
    0   1   2
0   a   b   c
1   1   4   7
2   2   5   8
3   3   6   9
4   d   e   f
5  10  13  16
6  11  14  17
7  12  15  18
```

Another example:

```
>>> df
   0  1  2   3   4   5   6   7   8
0  a  b  c   d   e   f   g   h   i
1  1  4  7  10  13  16  19  22  25
2  2  5  8  11  14  17  20  23  26
3  3  6  9  12  15  18  21  24  27

>>> pd.DataFrame(np.vstack(np.hsplit(df, df.shape[1] / 3)))
     0   1   2
0    a   b   c
1    1   4   7
2    2   5   8
3    3   6   9
4    d   e   f
5   10  13  16
6   11  14  17
7   12  15  18
8    g   h   i
9   19  22  25
10  20  23  26
11  21  24  27
```

Comment: this does work perfectly for me right now. Thanks for your Help. That was pretty fast and solid Solution!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DataFrame.append`:

```py
a = df[df.columns[: len(df.columns) // 3 + 1]]
b = df[df.columns[len(df.columns) // 3 + 1 :]]
b.columns = a.columns

df_out = a.append(b).reset_index(drop=True)
print(df_out)
```

Prints:

```
    0   1   2
0   a   b   c
1   1   4   7
2   2   5   8
3   3   6   9
4   d   e   f
5  10  13  16
6  11  14  17
7  12  15  18
```

---

EDIT: To handle unknown widths:

```py
dfs = []
for i in range(0, len(df.columns), 3):
    dfs.append(df[df.columns[i : i + 3]])
    dfs[-1].columns = df.columns[:3]

df_out = pd.concat(dfs)
print(df_out)
```

Prints:

```
    0   1   2
0   a   b   c
1   1   4   7
2   2   5   8
3   3   6   9
0   d   e   f
1  10  13  16
2  11  14  17
3  12  15  18
0   g   h   i
1  19  22  25
2  20  23  26
3  21  24  27
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your fast reply and efford to help me. As your solution does not work for and unknown width, I will not accept it. Anyways you were trying to help so i am grateful for your efford.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the additional efford and an alternative Solution. I cant accept two answers  at the same time sorry.